# Vim's "path" variable isn't changing or updating with modeline setting (finding header file in different directory)

Tags: path, modeline

I'm trying to do something relatively simple: Editing a file in `src` and pointing Vim to the header file located in `include`. My .vimrc file has `set modeline` on, and the first line in my file is: `// vim: set path += ../include` (I've also tried `include`, `include;`, and several other variations). When I look at the `path` variable:

`echo &path` gives me `.,/usr/include,,`; the path doesn't change regardless of what I put in the modeline.

`echo path` gives me nothing.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: That doesnt look like proper modeline or set syntax. Have you checked `:help modeline`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have, yes. There were also a couple of tutorials that used this syntax. I've tried different modeline syntaxes, altered spacing, etc. to no avail. What about is improper set syntax?

Comment: You need to get rid of the whitespace in the modeline option value. Also the modeline needs a trailing `:`. This should work from my limited testing: `// vim: set path+=../include:`  You can always check the result (after loading the file) using `:verbose set path?`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Ah, I missed the trailing colon. Thank you. :) If you include your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically, two forms of [modelines](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#modeline). Let me copy in the most important parts here together with an example:

```
 There are two forms of modelines.  The first form:
   [text{white}]{vi:vim:ex:}[white]{options}
 [...]
 Examples:
   vi:noai:sw=3 ts=6
 [...]
 The second form (this is compatible with some versions of Vi):
   [text{white}]{vi:vim:|Vim:ex:}[white]se[t] {options}:[text]
 [...]
 Examples:
   /* vim: set ai tw=75: */
```

Since you have been using the `:set` command, this means you are trying to create the latter form. There are two things to note here: First, you cannot use whitespace in the option value, otherwise Vim will parse those as separate options. The second is, you need to add a trailing `:` to indicate where the modeline ends.

This means, in your case, the complete line with the modeline should look like this:

```
// vim: set path+=../include:
```

Here is a simple tip, I use when creating a modeline. After reloading the file (`:e`), you can check the value of the options from the modeline by using `:verbose set path?`. Vim will output something like:

```
  path=.,,,../include
  Last set from modeline line 8
```